# Renaming a file in vim without changing its path

Tags: vim

I'm using [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script%5Fid=1928) to rename files, but I was wondering if it's possible to just specify a name change. For example, if I rename a file that's not in the `:pwd` and I don't specify its path, it will get moved to the current dir.

I'm using this mapping: `nnoremap <F6> :Rename`

So maybe I can put some variable after the :Rename command that will place the current file's relative path and name?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use mv from outside of VIM?

Comment: Because I don't want to switch and then re-open the file in vim

Comment: You could do it within Vim with `:!mv <oldname> <newname>`. In fact, in your case you could execute `:!mv % %:h/newname` and Vim would expand `%` to the current file name and `%:h` to the parent directory of the current file name when the command is executed. See `:help filename-modifiers`.

Comment: That is cool. Is there a way to include the modifier in a mapping? `<C-R>%:n` just appears to take % into account and :n is printed literally.

Comment: If you want to expand `%:h` (that's an `h`, not an `n`) before the command is executed, use `<C-R>=expand("%:h")<CR>`. The `=` refers to the expression register (See `:help c_CTRL-R_=`) which prompts for an expression. An expression may be a function call; `expand()` is a function that expands its argument. (See `:help expand()`.) The `<CR>` terminates the expression so that its value is placed where you typed the `Ctrl-R`. Your mapping could then be something like `nnoremap <F6> :!mv % <C-R>=expand("%:h")<CR>/`. Note that I chose to not expand the first `%`  until the command is executed.

Comment: I did meant `n` as I was reviewing the help as you indicated and it seemed n would work better for my needs. Anyway your code works perfectly! I'm beginning to understand all the raves about vim... I might even drop my current IDE for good if it continues to be this awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim keeps the current file name in the `%` register. You can insert the value of a register into the command line by typing `Ctrl-R` followed by the name of the register. Therefore, you should be able to type `<F6>` `Ctrl-R` `%` (without the intervening spaces) and see something like this on the command line:

```
:Rename /full/path/to/the/current/file
```

You can then edit the last component of the full path to change the name.

Note that Vim expands `%` to the full path name only if the current working directory is different from the file's parent directory. Otherwise, Vim expands `%` to just the file name.

See also

```
:help quote%
:help c_CTRL-R
```

Comment: Sweet! Any way of putting that in nnoremap? I tried `nnoremap <F6> :Rename <Ctrl>R %` but that just prints it literally instead of simulating the key presses.

Comment: Nevermind, it's `<C-R>%`